# Access a related table in EF Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, entity-framework-core, code-behind

I am trying to access a related table to display a column in my View.

I believe it is something quite fundamental I am not understanding but for the life of me can't solve it.

Simplified problem is, I have 3 Models Branch, Colleague, Staff Position. A Colleague currently is linked to 1 branch and can be only 1 Staff Positon.

Models are created using Code First
Branch

```
public class Branch
    {
        [Display(Name ="Branch ID")]
        public int BranchNumber { get; set; }
        [Display(Name ="Branch Name")]
        public string BranchName { get; set; }
        [Display(Name ="Contractor Code")]
        public int ContractorCode { get; set; }
        [Display(Name ="Addresss")]
        public string AddressOne { get; set; }
       ... (Excluded for simplicity)...

        public ICollection<BranchHour> BranchHours { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Colleague> Colleagues { get; set; }

        
    }
```

Colleague

```
public class Colleague
    {
        [Display(Name ="ID")]
        public int ColleagueID { get; set; }

        public int BranchID { get; set; }

        
        public int StaffPositionID { get; set; }

        [Display(Name ="Payroll Number")]
        public string PayrollNumber { get; set; }
        ...(Excluded for simplicity)...
        
        public ICollection<Shift> Shifts { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("StaffPositionID")]
        public StaffPosition StaffPosition { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("BranchID")]
        public Branch Branch { get; set; }
    }
```

Staff Position

```
public class StaffPosition
    {
        public int StaffPositionID { get; set; }
        public string PositionName { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Colleague> Colleagues { get; set; }
    }
```

I know that having the navigation properties in both classes is optional.

My View Model is

```
public class BranchShiftData
    {
        public IEnumerable<Branch> Branches { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Colleague> Colleagues { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Shift> Shifts { get; set; }             
        public IEnumerable<StaffPosition> StaffPos { get; set; }
    }
```

Originally I didn't have Shifts and Staff Pos in there but I couldn't access Shifts data through Colleague I would expect without it.

This is the start of the OnGet for the Code Behind page

```
BranchData = new BranchShiftData();
            BranchData.Branches = await _context.Branches
            .Include(i => i.Colleagues)                        
            .OrderBy(i => i.BranchNumber)
            .ToListAsync();

            if (id != null)
            {
                BranchID = id.Value;
                Branch branch = BranchData.Branches
                    .Where(i => i.ContractorCode == id.Value).Single();
                BranchData.Colleagues = branch.Colleagues
                .OrderBy(i => i.FullName);
            }

            if (colleagueID != null)
            {
                ColleagueID = colleagueID.Value;                
                var selectedColleague = BranchData.Colleagues
                    .Where(x => x.ColleagueID == colleagueID).Single();
               
                FullName = selectedColleague.FullName;
                PayrollNumber = selectedColleague.PayrollNumber;
                BranchName = selectedColleague.Branch.BranchName;
                ContractHours = selectedColleague.ContractHours;
                PositionName = selectedColleague.StaffPosition.PositionName;
```

So the issue I face is I am able to access the Branch Name by going through selectedColleague and its link to Branch, however, the same does not work for StaffPosition table and I can't understand why.
Once I select a single colleague in the web app it breaks at line starting PositionName due to the following error

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an
> object.

Which would be correct as the variables stack shows for the selectedColleague as StaffPosition null.

What I fail to understand is in the selectedColleague variable BranchID is 5558 (correct) and I have a object of Branch which when expanded is all the correct details for Branch 5558, however, selectedColleague's StaffPositionID is correct at 1 but yet StaffPosition is null.

The main question I have is why can I get the Branch name by going

```
BranchName = selectedColleague.Branch.BranchName
```

But can't access StaffPosition Name by going

```
PositionName = selectedColleague.StaffPosition.PositionName
```

### Post resolution update:

For anyone who comes across this,Serge's answer below is spot on. If you want to read further on the ThenInclude function then check here
[EF Core Docs](https://entityframeworkcore.com/querying-data-include-theninclude)
There is also another tutorial from MS hidden down in the docs list, this is for Razor pages but there is also one for MVC.
[MS Tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-rp/read-related-data?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio-code)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have Branck in  Branches already, but you have to add  include for a StaffPosition. Try this

```
    BranchData.Branches = await _context.Branches
            .Include(i => i.Colleagues)    
            .ThenInclude(i => i.StaffPosition)                        
            .OrderBy(i => i.BranchNumber)
            .ToListAsync();
```